# Add an OUTPUT inserted.columnname from an insert statement populated from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2016 and would like to know, is there a way to add an OUTPUT `inserted.columnname` from an insert statement from SELECT statement. I need to add a `ROW_NUMBER` in the #t temp table for a while statement below in my code. Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
CREATE TABLE #t (Id int, RN int)

INSERT INTO dbo.AUT_ReinsuranceAudit (
      UserSysID
    , ReinsuranceSysID
    , AuditType
    , DateRange
    , [ExpireDate]
    , [STATUS]
)
OUTPUT inserted.ReinsuranceAuditSysID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reins) AS RN
INTO #t
SELECT aul.UserSysID, @ReinsuranceID, 'Claims', LEFT(@ReinsuranceName + ' Claims Audit', 25), @AuditEndDate, 1
FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList aul;
```

When I run the code above, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
> Invalid column name 'ReinsuranceAuditSysID'.
> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Line 77 is the line with my `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: `ReinsuranceAuditSysID` isn't in the columns you `INSERT`, so that's why that's erroring; it doesn't exist in `inserted` as it tells you. As the the latter, the error is telling you why you can't use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: No it's the primary key from the table I'm inserting to and I'm trying to add those to my temp table #t.  Sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: You'll find using the output clause with `merge` more useful, you can output all columns, not just the inserted.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I've not use the OUTPUT clause before and just trying to figure out what works.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add the table definition for `AUT_ReinsuranceAudit`

Comment: Charlie, I actually found a fix using a MERGE as suggested by Stu. I'm testing my code but thanks anyway.